# How to choose the directory where i want to save the Java documentation?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, javadoc

I'm working with jenkins, i created a project with maven , so when i build the project in jenkins i create the documentation just with the follow goal:

javadoc:javadoc

but jenkins save all this documentation in some folder inside of the project, so i want save all this documentation in a specific folder.

Comment: [outputDirectory](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#outputDirectory): Specifies the destination directory where javadoc saves the generated HTML files.

Comment: Did you notice that when you let Jenkins do its thing, it nicely makes the Javadoc available to the Jenkins users, through the menu on the left?

Comment: Better use **mvn site** to create the whole site which includes JavaDoc.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achive this is by modifying the plugin configuration for this. reportOutputDirectory and destDir are the two configurations you might want to look at.

Take a look at Maven's [Documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/output-configuration.html)